# How Do I Swap Page Logo With Different Logo When Hovering Over Specific Nav Links

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm sure this is fairly simple using jquery, but I cannot figure it out. I have a site with logo that is present when the site loads. I want to swap that logo with a different logo when the user hovers over a certain navigation link.

When hovering over the "com" link, I want to swap the site logo for a different one.

Can someone tell me how to accomplish this with jquery.

```
<div>
<div id="logo"><img src="myimage.png"></div>
<div id="menu">
     <ul>
       <li><a href="#">res</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">com</a></li>

    </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: As Ruben van Dijk has pointed out, sprites would be better for this. It would be quicker as the image is loaded on page load and there's no need for javascript as you're using css hover.

Comment: Makes sense except how would I get the logo to change when hovering over the link? Wouldn't it just load the sprite image in the nav rather than shifting to other logo in #logo? Still new to sprites.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can do it with jQuery using attr

Give res a class. The hover name should be myimage-hover.png

```
$(function () {
    $('a.res').hover( function () {
        $(.logo img).attr('src', $(.logo img).attr('src').replace(/\.png/, '-hover.png') );
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It might also be worth your time checking into sprites.

Comment: For what the OP wants to do, I would suggest sprites as well.

Answer (score 0):

This would be one way:

```
$('a:contains("com")').mouseover(function(){
    $('#logo img').prop('src','http://www.placekitten.com/100/100')
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/D2X5V/)**